# bxSlider carousel showing only 1 slide

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm tyring to reproduce a carousel kinda like that one : http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides

The only difference being that mine would include html content rather than simple images.
Here's basically the HTML structure :

```
<ul class="slider">
  <li>
    <a href=""><img SRC=""></a>
    <div>some content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><img SRC=""></a>
    <div>some content</div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

and here's the JS :

```
$('ul.slider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 2,
  slideWidth: 360,
  slideMargin: 10
});
```

There must be something I didn't catch, because the result is that the slider is only showing 1 item at the time, when I would like it to display at least 2 images up to more. What's wrong with my code ?

You can see the live example here : http://rommy.hd.free.fr/stillgood/index.php

If you look under the big main image, here is the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself. The version of the bxSlider js file I was using wasn't the one used on their website, so a fresh redownload made it!